# Retrieving ID3 Tag information from HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, http-live-streaming

We are able to play HTTP live streaming (HLS) video streams from android by specifying "httplive://REAL_URL/main.m3u8"

Is there any way to retrieve timed metadata from HTTP live streaming (HLS) in android?
or 
Is there any specific libraries.

We have package called 'MediaMetaDataRetriever' in android which works for MP3 files

In iOS - we have property called 'TimedMetadata'

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I need to do a similar thing!

Answer (score 0):

If the metadata comes at the beginning of the stream the MediaMetaDataRetriever must be able to extract it. Some MP3 files, on the other hand, have the ID3 metadata at the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is it possible to read metadata from Mpeg Transport Streams instead of mp3 files?

Comment: @Samaurai did using MediaMetaDataRetriever solve your problem?